# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundImage' of undefined althout js is called after page loads

Tags: javascript, html, css, onload

I thought that by using  `$(document).ready(function(){})` right before `</body>` the page will have loaded but when i try to set the background image through javascript I get :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundImage' of undefined.
```

The code is:

```
<body>
<div class="bottom_header"></div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  doSlideshow();

  function doSlideshow()
  {
     var x = document.getElementsByClassName("bottom_header");
     x.style.backgroundImage = "url('s1.jpg')";
  }
})
</script>
</body>
```

I also tried the following but results in the same `typeError`. I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
<body>
<div class="bottom_header"></div>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    alert("it's in");
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("bottom_header");
    x.style.backgroundImage = "url('s1.jpg')";
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns one or more elements, so you'll need to get the first such element (or iterate over them).

Comment: Actually although i'm sure i tried it with id, now that i tried again it worked...silly mistake thank you. But why it doesn't work with document.getElementsByClassName since i use class = "bottom_header" only on the specific div?

Comment: It returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which is why you still need to iterate/index even if it's just one item.